# Giving formats to macro variables

Tags: macros, sas, format

I am really confused by the formats given to macro variables. Two variables are tried to formatted. One is working and one is not!

The code is:

```
proc format;
    value classgrp
    1 = 'Total Resurfacing'
    2 = 'Cemented Total Conventional'
    3 = 'Cementless Total Conventional'
    4 = 'Hybrid Total Conventional'

    value hrtp
    1='0-1Mth'
    2='1Mth-'
    3='3Mth-'
    4='1Yr-'
    5='5Yr-'
    6='10Yr+'
    ;
run;


%macro t(varfmt,tpfmt);
%do m=2 %to 3;
    %let mformat=%sysfunc(putn(&m., &varfmt.));
    %let tpformat=%sysfunc(putn(&m., &tpfmt.));

    %put ****variable &mformat.*****;
    %put ****time period &tpformat.*****;
%end;

%mend;

%t(varfmt=classgrp.,tpfmt=hrtp.);
```

The outputs are

WARNING: Argument 2 to function PUTN referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is
         out of range.
****variable Cemented Total Conventional*****
****time period *****
WARNING: Argument 2 to function PUTN referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is
         out of range.
****variable Cementless Total Conventional*****
****time period *****

Just classgrp formats are successfully transferred to macro variable "mformat". So why could not macro variable tpformat get formats from hrtp?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: I don't get any errors. Check your earlier code for errors - you're missing a semicolon to end the first format.

Comment: Ha, Reeza, eagle eyes! Thanks! Just focused on the arguments, did not pay attention to the semicolons.